# Flexbox styling not applying to elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

No matter how I style an element, none of the Flexbox styles I apply work. I have searched everywhere for a solution but could not find any (apologies if this is a duplicate as I could not find an answer to the problem).

I have created a [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/Myzostal/pen/pgoXav).

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.test {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    background: #333;
}

.test2 {
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 2.5em;
    background: #ff0000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: There is no question here.  Perhaps you could clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add those CSS rules to the parent element instead.

When you set `display: flex` on an element, its direct children elements become flexbox items. In your example, the `.test2` elements didn't have any children elements, so I assume you were probably wanting to add `display: flex` on the parent element instead.

```css
.test {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.test2 {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It really helped! Don't have enough rep to publicly up-vote so +1.